# reload after print page failing in firefox

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I want to print a page from another page,
currently I am  using iframe and window.location.replace() to reload which works fine in chrome when i try it Firefox page is printing but not reloading my code as follows:

```
$('.print').html('<iframe src="print-page.php?parameter=something" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.replace('<?php echo @$redirect_url;?>');
            }, 2000);
```

Thanks in advance.